# Puppet: Evaluating variables inside onlyif close

Tags: puppet

I have a variable that I set at a very early stage, the variable is boolean, then at some point I want to `exec` a command based on the fact if this variable is true or false, something like this:

```
exec { 'update-to-latest-core': 
  command     => "do something",
  user        => 'root',
  refreshonly => true,
  path        => [ "/bin/bash", "sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ], 
  onlyif      => 'test ${latest} =      true',
  notify      => Exec["update-to-latest-database"],
}
```

So this command doesn't work (`onlyif => ['test ${latest} = true'],`) I tried several other ways too, but didn't work. Something so simple cannot be so hard to do. Can someone help me with this, and also explain the rules behind getting commands to execute inside `onlyif` close. (also I cannot use if-close on a higher level because I have other dependencies )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$latest` is a *Puppet* variable, it is not useful to defer checking its value until the catalog is applied.  Technically, in fact, you cannot do so: Puppet will interpolate the variable's value into the `Exec` resource's catalog representation, so there is no variable left by the time the catalog is applied, only a literal.

Since the resource in question is notified by another resource, you must not suppress it altogether.  If the code presented in your question does not work, then it is likely because the interpolated value of `$latest` is different than you expect -- for example, '1' instead of 'true'.  Running the agent in `--debug` mode should show you the details of the command being executed.

Alternatively, you could approach it a different way:

```
exec { 'update-to-latest-core': 
  command     => $latest ? { true => "do something", default => '/bin/true' },
  user        => 'root',
  refreshonly => true,
  path        => [ "/bin/bash", "sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ], 
  notify      => Exec["update-to-latest-database"],
}
```

That will execute (successfully, and with no external effect) whenever `$latest` is `false`, and it will run your `do something` command whenever `$latest` is `true`.  The choice of command is made during catalog building.

Comment: Thank you @John Bollinger A lot !! , your suggested solution works like a charm

Comment: what if that `exec` is used as a prerequisite of another step? It will just be evaluated as succesful even when have done nothing and the dependant statement will be executed too. I am not sure is the right solution

Comment: The right solution to what, @Raffaello?  This has exactly the effect the OP was going for, including that the `Exec` succeeds in the event that variable `$latest` has a falsey value.  That is the result when, as the OP originally attempted, an `Exec`'s command is not run at all on account of the result of its `onlyif` or `unless` command.

Comment: well general solution, pattern, to this kind of question exec onlyif $latest == true. 
In the case $latest != true, it won't stop there if there is a chain of statements: exec {} -> somethingElse { } .

Basically with a default true results that the exec will be anyway executed succesfully, so it runs the somethingElse {} statement, bypassing completely the semantic of the operator `->`. right?

Comment: agree it is perfectly fine just for the scope of the question.